# rails set correct user and verify if user is admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter

In my controller, I have a def that verifies if its the correct user. A normal user can only edit,update and destroy his own tweets.

```
before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
```

Now I would like to grant admin the rights to edit,update and destroy any tweet as well as admin's tweets

How do I combine both definitions?

```
private


def verify_is_admin
  @card = @tweet.card.id
  (current_user.nil?) ? redirect_to(root_path) : (redirect_to card_path(@card), notice: 'Not authorised to update this tweet' unless current_user.admin?)
end

def correct_user
  @card = @tweet.card.id
  @tweet = current_user.tweets.find_by(id: params[:id])
  redirect_to card_path(@card), notice: 'Not authorised to update this tweet' if @tweet.nil?
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to combine them in a new method or in one of the existing? If you want a new method you can do something like this:

```
def can_edit_tweet?
  true if (currrent_user.admin? || correct_user)
end
```

and change your `before_action` to:

```
before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy, :can_edit_tweet?]
```

If you want to combine them into one you can edit the `correct_user` method:

```
def correct_user
  @card = @tweet.card.id
  @tweet = current_user.tweets.find_by(id: params[:id])
  redirect_to card_path(@card), notice: 'Not authorised to update this tweet' if (@tweet.nil? && !current_user.admin?)
end
```